# How can I use regex to match the contents which is end with "$" by using expect?

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression, expect

I want to perform some commands to remote server by using `expect`. But when I use `.*\$$` it always cannot match the remote prompt to send the commands.

The following it my script:

```bsh
#!/bin/ksh
while read -r line; do
/usr/linux/bin/expect -c "
set timeout 20
spawn ssh padmin@$line
expect {
    -re \".*(P|p)assword:\" {send \"$2\r\"}
}
expect {
    -re \".*\$$\" {send \"ls -lt cfgbackups|grep gz|head -n 1|awk '{print \$9}'\r\"}
}
expect {
    -re \".*\$$\" {exit 0}
    eof {exit 0}
}
send_user \"$expect_out(1,string)\n\"
" 2>"$line".errlog &
done <"$1"
```

When I use the debug mode to check, I got these messages:

```bsh
expect version 5.45.4
spawn ssh padmin@192.168.0.1
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {3474502}
Gate keeper glob pattern for '(P|p)assword:' is ''. Not usable, disabling the performance booster.

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "(P|p)assword:"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no
padmin@192.168.0.1's password: 
expect: does "padmin@192.168.0.1's password: " (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "(P|p)assword:"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "password:"
expect: set expect_out(1,string) "p"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "padmin@192.168.0.1's password:"
send: sending "padmin\r" to { exp4 }
Gate keeper glob pattern for '^:.*$' is ':*'. Activating booster.

expect: does " " (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "^:.*$"? Gate ":*"? gate=no
"send_user"? no


expect: does " \r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "^:.*$"? Gate ":*"? gate=no
"send_user"? no
Last unsuccessful login: Tue Jul  7 03:04:50 BEIST 2020 on ssh from 192.168.0.5
Last login: Tue Jul  7 15:18:11 BEIST 2020 on ssh from 192.168.0.4
Welcome!
/etc/profile[63]: hostname:  not found.

expect: does " \r\nLast unsuccessful login: Tue Jul  7 03:04:50 BEIST 2020 on ssh from 192.168.0.5\r\nLast login: Tue Jul  7 15:18:11 BEIST 2020 on ssh from 192.168.0.4\r\nWelcome!\r\n/etc/profile[63]: hostname:  not found.\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "^:.*$"? Gate ":*"? gate=yes re=no
"send_user"? no
:/home/padmin$ 
expect: does " \r\nLast unsuccessful login: Tue Jul  7 03:04:50 BEIST 2020 on ssh from 192.168.0.5\r\nLast login: Tue Jul  7 15:18:11 BEIST 2020 on ssh from 192.168.0.4\r\nWelcome!\r\n/etc/profile[63]: hostname:  not found.\r\n:/home/padmin$ " (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "^:.*$"? Gate ":*"? gate=yes re=no
"send_user"? no
expect: timed out
Gate keeper glob pattern for '^:.*$' is ':*'. Activating booster.

expect: does " \r\nLast unsuccessful login: Tue Jul  7 03:04:50 BEIST 2020 on ssh from 192.168.0.5\r\nLast login: Tue Jul  7 15:18:11 BEIST 2020 on ssh from 192.168.0.4\r\nWelcome!\r\n/etc/profile[63]: hostname:  not found.\r\n:/home/padmin$ " (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "^:.*$"? Gate ":*"? gate=yes re=no
sighandler: handling signal(2)
async event handler: Tcl_Eval(exit 130)
```

So how can I fix the problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you edit your question to include the command line by which you call your script, and the exact error message you get? That would help pin the problem down ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem is the `$` symbol. When I use the `\\\$` as expect output the script works fine. Cause the `$` is also a special symbol in regex. When we use the `\$` the regex would indicate it as an regex ending symbol. So we need do use `\\\$` to convert it as `\$`. That's all. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the string being passed to `/usr/linux/bin/expect -c ...`; what does the command actually receive? If we replace the command by `echo` we can see the output being given to expect:

```
expect {
    -re ".*$" {send "ls -lt cfgbackups|grep gz|head -n 1|awk '{print $9}'\r"}
}
```

Now let's do the same thing with the string being passed to `send`. This time we have to use `expect` to parse the string, so we replace the `send` by an expect command like `send_user`:

```
expect <<\!
send_user "ls -lt cfgbackups|grep gz|head -n 1|awk '{print $9}'\r"
!
```

This produces an error from expect:

```
can't read "9": no such variable
```

So we need to stop expect from interpolating the `$9`, by using `\$9`.

Going backwards to the original ksh script, to produce a single `\` in the double-quoted string we need to use `\\`. So finally, the fix is:

```
expect {
    -re \".*$\" {send \"ls -lt cfgbackups|grep gz|head -n 1|awk '{print \\\$9}'\r\"}
}
```

---

You can reduce these sorts of problems by alternating single quotes and double quotes, provided there is no space between them. Eg: `echo "hi"'there'` produces `hithere`, and `echo '"who'"'s"'"'` produces `"who's"`. And also using `<<!` and `<<\!` style of here-documents provides another level of quoting.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the command problem and  reply so quickly. But the problem was it didn't send the command to the remote. I have put the all debug details into the question. Would you please take a look again?

Answer (score 0):

When mixing expect code into a shell script, it's best to use a heredoc. Then you avoid at least one level of quoting hell. In Tcl/expect, regular expressions are best braced not quoted, makes handling backslashes easier.

```bsh
/usr/linux/bin/expect <<END_EXPECT 2>"$line".errlog &
    set timeout 20
    spawn ssh padmin@$line
    expect {
        -re {.*(P|p)assword:} {send "$2\r"}
    }
    expect {
        -re {.*\$$} {send "ls -lt cfgbackups|grep gz|head -n 1|awk '{print \$9}'\r"}
    }
    expect {
        -re {.*\$$} {exit 0}
        eof {exit 0}
    }
    send_user "$expect_out(1,string)\n"
END_EXPECT
```

I'm not sure if the newlines and carriage returns should be written `\r` or `\\r` -- you can experiment with that.

You can pass shell variables to expect through the environment, then you can quote the entire heredoc:

```bsh
host="$line" passwd="$2" /usr/linux/bin/expect <<'END_EXPECT' 2>"$line".errlog &
    # ...........................................^..........^
    set timeout 20
    spawn ssh padmin@$env(host)
    expect {
        -re {.*(P|p)assword:} {send "$env(passwd)\r"}
    }
    expect {
        -re {.*\$$} {send "ls -lt cfgbackups|grep gz|head -n 1|awk '{print \$9}'\r"}
    }
    expect {
        -re {.*\$$} {exit 0}
        eof {exit 0}
    }
    send_user "$expect_out(1,string)\n"
END_EXPECT
```

What is the purpose of the `send_user` line? You're not capturing anything in any expect patterns, and you're actually exiting expect in the last `expect` command. What do you think you'll see there?

Comment: For `send_user` I just want to catch the command outputs. I'll try to use heredoc in shell script. But the problem was the expect didn't send any command to the remote. So I think maybe it's the regex problem. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: That's because the shell will substitute `\r` in double quotes with a `r` not a carriage return. So your code never "hits enter". Double the backslashes.

Comment: I don't think it's the backslashes problem. In my case, the password has been sent successfully, but the command was not.Even I use the double backslashes, it's the same.